# how can i open a specific text file in a text editor in a bash script?

Tags: bash, text, text-editor

I wish to open a text file e.g. loopy.txt in a text editor with a bash script.

How can it be done programmatically, please?

Comment: like `vim loopy.txt` ?

Comment: The best way to do it is to use something like `"${EDITOR:-vi}" loopy.txt` which will open the file in default editor of fallbacks to vi. Regards

Comment: sorry doesn't work for me.

Comment: Did  you set the value of `EDITOR`? Do you have `vi` installed on your machine? What editor do you want to use? *What* exactly doesn't work?

Comment: I have vi installed. Just no text editor opened. Tried it with gedit, too

Answer (score 0):

The answer that works for me was a simple:
gedit 'filename'
or emacs 'filename'